# Googlemaps OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I am facing a strange problem concerning Google Maps' geocoding/reverse geocoding service.

My iPhone app uses Google Maps services in order to geocode addresses or reverse geocode points of a map view. The URLs I am using are:

```
#define WS_GEOCODE      @"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode  /json?address=%@&sensor=true&l anguage=%@"
#define WS_REV_GEOCODE  @"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%@,%@&sensor=true&language=%@"
```

The problem is that when I use Wifi everything works well, but when I access internet through the carrier's network I always get googlemaps status `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps has very strict limits for personal use. I guess that the IP it detects has been using their service too much and has been blocked. Next step is the professional paying service which costs $10K .... a year ....

May I suggest (as I just did the switch myself yesterday) to use Bing's geocoding service. It works nearly as good and the limits for free use are A LOT higher than google's. Google kicks you out after 2500 requests per day. a Bing "developer" app allows 250.000 calls a year or something like that.

Comment: 2500 per day is more than 250,000 per year

Comment: but it is not capped to 2500 / day

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the topology of your connection in the case of mobile carrier: your phone connects to the carrier server through an APN, the carrier server forwards the requests on your behalf. The external IP that Google Maps API sees is always that of your carrier.

The Google Maps API terms of use say something about usage limit; so I'm thinking there's a possibility that a lot of devices connected to the same server generate quite an amount of requests and reach that limit cumulatively.

Answer (score 0):

there is a tricky for this... 
with php you can use sleep function to delay another request [php sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)